# Git out of sync scenario, with my commit left in between?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

So this a peculiar scenario which i have come across many times and have not been to able to figure out a viable workflow out of this.

Scenario
I have a remote git branch the repo has some maintainer. I have local clone of the repo and me and the maintainer are working on same branch at a time. Both the remote and local are in sync. Now the maintainer asks me to add a feature. I make certain changes and branch out to a different branch commit, push and create a pr to main branch. But meanwhile the maintainer had made certain commits to the main branch.

so the pr which i made from the feature branch is out of sync in terms of commit history being some commits behind the main branch.

To get them in sync and have only one commit in pr, i do a manual process of moving back to main branch pulling from the origin creating a new branch named feature2 and making the same changes, which i had earlier made in my feature branch to feature2 and create a new pr again from the feature2 to main branch and delete the initial feature branch and its pr.

Which seems a wrong way to it also consuming lot of time. What would be the right way and flow to tackle such scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to merge the master (main) branch into your feature branch to sync.

1. Pull the master branch
2. Checkout your feature branch
3. merge the master branch into your feature branch

Here's a nice gist with required git commands. https://gist.github.com/santisbon/a1a60db1fb8eecd1beeacd986ae5d3ca

In that way, it will sync your branch with the latest changes.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
git fetch <remote_repo>
git rebase <remote_repo>/master topic
```

before issuing a second pull request.

So the operation you are manually making is already automated in git with rebase operation.

from [git manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

> ```
>       A---B---C topic
>      /
> D---E---F---G master
> ```
>
> From this point, the result of either of the following commands:
>
> `git rebase master`
>
> `git rebase master topic`
>
> would be:
>
> ```
>               A'--B'--C' topic
>              /
> D---E---F---G master
> ```